# Motorola Defy + Keeps Rebooting

Tags: reboot, boot-loop, motorola-defy

I bought another Defy + for my daughter. I also have one which is fine.

Hers keeps shutting down and rebooting, especially when it's away from the WiFi. It also has the latest system update. We tried switching batteries, but hers kept rebooting so it's not a battery issue.

Any help out there?

Comment: Not enough data to give a thorough answer. Could be a misbehaving app, or something screwed up. Did you try it the hard way (factory reset)?

Answer (score 0):

Its a faulty phone. Take it back and get a new one.

But you can turn off mobile data and it will stop rebooting.

or search google for "Motorola Defy+ Rebooting" for other opinons